# How do I finish this summations problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have posted a picture since I don't know how to make the summation symbols with the lower and upper summations on keyboard, sorry about that..

$$\sum_{a=1}^9\sum_{b=0}^9(101a+10b)$$

The answer is $49,500$, and I am not sure how I am supposed to solve this. The book does have the steps, but they are all alien to me because it doesn't explain how they got from one step to the other.

To be precise I am confused about how they managed to bring $101a + 10b$ into the middle of the two summations, turning it into $\sum_{a=1}^9 (10(101a)+10)\sum_{b=0}^9 b$

Here is what I am referring to, [image]

Comment: It would help if you went back to the solutions in the book and told us exactly which steps you couldn't understand.

Comment: Okay i just edited and added what i am confused about, it's basically the first step. I wrote "summation" in palce of summation symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}\left(101a+10b\right)=\sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}101a+\sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}10b$$
$$=101\sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}a+10\sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}b=101\times10\left(\sum_{a=1}^9a\right)+10\times9\sum_{b=0}^9b=\left(1010\times45\right)+\left(90\times45\right)=49,500$$

In the second summation I first summed over $a$ which is not present and hence $10b$ is added $9$ times. Hence $10 \times 9$.

Comment: how did you get 10 x 9?

Comment: @user3718584   now have a look

Comment: I am stuck on your 4th step where you did 101x10 and 10x9, because you say it is 10 x 9, for you summand over a which is not present. How do you summand over a which is not present?

Answer (score 0):

The $101a$ doesn't depend on $b$, so you can distribute it out.  Then the $10b$ doesn't depend on $a$ so it will distribute as well.  Do you know $\sum_{i=0}^n i=\frac 12n(n-1)$?  Do you see how this applies?

After your "To be precise" edit:  The first term is responding to the fact that it doesn't depend on $b$, so is constant in that sum.  The factor $10$ comes from the number of terms.  The $10$ comes from the common factor on the $10b$ to get the pattern above.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems can't resist solving even though they have been solved by others or answered by others.  Here is what I did.  I am poor at writing math equations on computer so wrote on paper and attached the photo.
[image: solution or answer to the question]